# Change the Format of the Date in VBA

Tags: vba, date, format

I think this is a basic question but I do not find a way to solve my problem

I created this code :

```
Sub test()

Range("A11") = CDate(Evaluate("WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)"))
Range("A11").NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
MsgBox Range("A11")


End Sub
```

But my problem is that the MsgBox do not take into account the NumberFormat `"yyyymmdd"`, it shows `"3/5/2021"` instead of `"20210305"`. It there a way to change the code so that when I write `MsgBox Range("A11")` it shows directly `"20210305"` ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the inbuilt VBA function `FormatDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the cell, you will most likely see `3/5/2021` as the value of the cell. Because it hasn't really changed, just the cell formatting.

`MsgBox Range("A11")` is the same as `MsgBox Range("A11").Value`, which will give you the value of the cell, without the formatting.
Try using `MsgBox Range("A11").Text` instead.